# are there compelling reasons to switch from php 5.3 to 5.2?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis

My boss created an application in php 5.2 on some older server. The application writes and reads data from a sql server 2012 database.

We now have a brand spankin new windows server 2012 with iis 8 on it.

My job is to migrate the application from the old server to the new server.

I've already installed php 5.3 not knowing that we need 5.2

**Question**

1. should I downgrade?
2. if so, how do i downgrade? the process of installing 5.3 is easy, but 5.2 is going to be a nightmare.

**example**
this will only work in versions 5.3+:

```
$serverName = '(localdb)\v11.0';
$connOptions = array('AttachDBFileName'=>'C:\Users\bswan\ExampleDB.mdf','Database'=>'ExampleDB');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connOptions);
if($conn === false)      
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
else
    echo "Connected via sqlsrv!<br />";
```

Comment: depends on what deprecated things the application does.. i seriously doubt 5.3 will be a problem. but, 5.2 is lacking a lot of modern usage, like the static method :: class reference by variable, namespaces..

Comment: @MarshallHouse thank you thats great information. do you know off hand how does very basic php 5.2 differ from 3

Comment: the biggest thing to me is in OOP wher you have a class: Clients and you reference it by variable `$clients = new Clients();` and try to call a static method: `$clients::isSomething()` will error in 5.2 so you have to call it like this: `$clients->isSomething()`. bare bones php there aren't any significant differences.

Comment: @MarshallHouse i didnt know php programmers use OO :)

Comment: it's turning into a very solid OOP language.

Comment: cool! completely off topic but what do you think of php vs go/python(from google) ?

Comment: sorry, one server side scripting language is enough for me. never tried anything else. PHP just has the most help available i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [what has changed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php) in 5.3. I would take the time to test to see if everything works fine with your application in 5.3 and if it does then you shouldn't downgrade. It's best to stay on the latest version if you can. If you insist on downgrading you can check this [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703676/how-to-downgrade-php-version-from-5-3-to-5-2-in-ubuntu-12-04) post.

Comment: thanks! there's a lengthy process of getting 5.2 to work with sql server i think

Answer (score 3):

There are NO valid reasons for downgrading. If you have a new system, you should be installing PHP 5.4.

Comment: agree with you! but i dont know if it's worth the time changing the code as we are trying to phase out the app

Comment: For the most part, PHP 5.2 code is compatible with 5.4, provided you weren't using bad practices.

Comment: Famous last words: 'we are trying to phase out the app'

Comment: @GlennStevens lol definitely right!